# NameError: name 'dates' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am getting an error "NameError: name 'dates' is not defined" when I'm trying to call dates.MonthLocator()

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv('tcs.csv', index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)

idx = df1.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-02-01'].index
stk = df1.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-02-01']['Close Price']

fig,ax =plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(idx,stk,'-')

# ax.xaxis.grid(True)
# ax.yaxis.grid(True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%b-%y"))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
```

and I am getting a Name error.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-32ecec70e866> in <module>
     13 # ax.yaxis.grid(True)
     14 
---> 15 ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
     16 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%b-%y"))
     17 

NameError: name 'dates' is not defined
```

Here is how df1 looks like.

[image: Screenshot]

Please let me know why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to import the submodule "dates" from matplotlib.

Add this line of code to your imports

```
from matplotlib import dates
```

Answer (score 1):

"dates" is a module from matplotlib (If I've understood well).
So you have to import "matplotlib.dates" to use this, like:

```
>>> from matplotlib import dates
>>> dates.MonthLocator
<class 'matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator'>
```